# What would be a good telescope to buy for amateur practice? [ Specifications in description ]

Tags: amateur-observing, photography

I'm a beginner in Astronomy in general and would like to have something like this with which I could do amateur photography and generally practice.

What would be a good telescope to buy with the following specifications:

- Magnification: 250x - 500x
- Mount with controller and camera ( Software would be preferable )

Regarding budget I know that these specifications can be costly and expensive but I would be comfortable with anything under 900, 1000 USD.

I did some research regarding this, I have some choices but I think that asking here I would get more interesting choices that I could put in my research from someone that's more experienced.

Comment: for that budget you should buy yourself an eight-inch dobsonian and the book "turn left at orion", then after a few months treat yourself to a new eyepiece

Comment: Very interesting Aaron. Short but informative. I will add this into my research. Thanks!

Comment: i'm sorry i don't have time to write a proper answer right now. but if i were you then i would forget about doing astrophotography at the moment: trying to do it with inexpensive equipment is very frustrating and time-consuming. and you'll spend more time playing with equipment and software than you will looking at the sky. if you like learning from videos then this might be useful for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpVwN21X2QA (his channel's good - i don't tend to watch a lot of astronomy videos but i have time for this guy)

Comment: After further research, Aaron you are absolutely right. I already got some old refractor telescope with 100x magnification and with broken stand and it's extremely annoying to just set it up to point it at anything just to get the picture of a dot or two. Anyway I will still continue researching astronomy, read the book and watch some of the videos of the channel you you've suggested me. Thanks again!